# Using DexClassLoader to perform custom class loading

Tags: android

I want to perform custom class loading using `DexClassLoader`, by following tutorial http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

First, I use Ant to build facebook, by setting `android.library=false`.

- An APK will be generated facebook-release.apk
- I use `dex2jar` and decompiler to exam `classes.dex` inside `facebook-release.apk`, seems ok to me.
  [image]

Then, I include this apk file in my project `assets` folder. I wish to use its classes during runtime, here is what I did.

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(File... dexInternalStoragePaths) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return null;
        }

        final File dexInternalStoragePath = dexInternalStoragePaths[0]; 

        if (false == dexInternalStoragePath.exists()) {
            prepareDex(dexInternalStoragePath);
        }

        // Internal storage where the DexClassLoader writes the optimized dex file to.
        final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // /data/data/org.yccheok.jstock.gui/app_dex/facebook-release.apk exists : true
        Log.i("CHEOK", dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath() + " exists : " + dexInternalStoragePath.exists());

        // /data/data/org.yccheok.jstock.gui/app_outdex exists : true
        Log.i("CHEOK", optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath() + " exists : " + optimizedDexOutputPath.exists());

        // Initialize the class loader with the secondary dex file.
        DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                null,
                getClassLoader());
        Class libProviderClazz = null;

        try {
            // Load the library class from the class loader.
            libProviderClazz = cl.loadClass("com.facebook.LibraryProvider");

            // Cast the return object to the library interface so that the
            // caller can directly invoke methods in the interface.
            // Alternatively, the caller can invoke methods through reflection,
            // which is more verbose and slow.
            LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) libProviderClazz.newInstance();

            // Display the toast!
            lib.activateApp(JStockFragmentActivity.this, "470806879684614");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Handle exception gracefully here.
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("CHEOK", exception.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I had confirmed all the passed in parameters to `DexClassLoader` is correct, by logging its `dexInternalStoragePath` and `optimizedDexOutputPath`.

However, the exception is being thrown during `DexClassLoader.loadClass`

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.JStockFragmentActivity$PrepareDexTask.doInBackground(JStockFragmentActivity.java:120)
```

Is there anything I had missed out?

Comment: did you resolve this issue already?  I'm running into a similar issue with resolving a fragment from a different APK than the main application APK.  I also noticed some output in LOGCAT which indicated the fragment class was resovled differently in each APK.

Comment: Just curious why you are doing this? If it is because of the 65536 method reference limit issue, I would suggest you just use Proguard to strip out unused code. Much simpler than custom class loading.

Comment: @EricSchlenz If I were able to solve using Proguard, I wouldn't be shooting myself using this complicated approach :)

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Bummer. I just recently ran into the 65536 method reference limit, and found that same Facebook article. The idea of having to go the custom class loading route just didn't sit well with me. Luckily, I was able to use Proguard to significantly shrink the amount of code. So I'm now well below that limit. Sounds like you've researched this enough already, and are unable to use Proguard though. Good luck Cheok, hope it works out for you.